# Mocha-chai throws error from generator in Node

Tags: node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, generator

this code https://jsfiddle.net/0px2tsvb/ throws error

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\wamp\www\clearanceForm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:226:19)
```

but when I change line 50 to test which should not pass, like

```
savedUser.should.not.eql(foundUser);
```

error is not thrown anymore and... test is passed. Why is that? What's wrong?

Edit:
I've modified asyncTest to output objects:

```
function *asyncTest(first, second) {
    let sth = new test_model({first: first, second: second});
    let savedUser = yield asyncPromiseUtil(sth.save());
    let foundUser = yield asyncPromiseUtil(test_model.findById(savedUser._id));
    console.log(savedUser);
    console.log(foundUser);
    savedUser.should.not.eql(foundUser);
    done();
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{ _id: 5753e798b80a84781a86d024,
  second: '123',
  first: 'asda',
  __v: 0 }
{ __v: 0,
  second: '123',
  first: 'asda',
  _id: 5753e798b80a84781a86d024 }
```

Comment: what are you getting in savedUser and foundUser?  Are these objects comparable? I would suggest share the objects you are getting that will help us.

Comment: You should not use `done` with mocha when using promises - it has promises support. When you use the `done`  callback you confuse it - chances are that if you remove it the code will work. 

What happens is that your assertion fails (as you can see) and the code throws never reaching `done`. If your code used mocha promise syntax that would turn into a promise rejection which would get caught by mocha and treated as a failure.

Comment: Please post your code in your question, not to jsfiddle - especially if it's not a html fiddle, but node.js code.

Comment: You should use a generator/coroutine runner library instead of implementing your own `asyncPromiseUtil`.